# R Datatables custom buttons

Tags: r, datatables, dt

I'm relatively new with the DT package in R, but I'm trying to customize the output of CSV files when a button is clicked. I've been following along with the last of [these examples](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.action), but my code is not working. Here is my .Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(DT)
```


```{r results='hide'}
dt <-
  datatable(iris,
            extensions = 'Buttons',
            options = list(pageLength = 5, dom = 'Blfrtip', buttons = list(
              list(
                extend = 'csv',
                text = 'Create Custom CSV',
                action = DT::JS(
                  "function (e, dt, button, config) {
                  // Eventually process some data
                  $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.csvHtml5.action.call(this, e, dt, node, config);
                  }"
                )
              )
            )))
```

`r dt`
````

The idea is that I do some processing of the data then simply call the default csvHtml5 action. In my example, I'm just looking to return the default csv action but when I click the 'Create Custom CSV' button in the knitted HTML file, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace

```
function (e, dt, button, config)
```

with

```
function (e, dt, node, config)
```